# Update model field when creating from another model instance which is ForeignKey related

Tags: django, django-models

I started car fleet app and created a few models in models related file, I did models hierarchy that on top I have the car brand, below ForeignKey related car models to each brand, and ForeignKey for each car id that eventually consists the car inventory,  which is called "class CarPool", in this model I have value "car_sale_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)", what I would like to achieve is each time I create an instance from associated ForeignKey of the seller will update automatically "car_sale_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)" to True

Please advice

Thanks

```
class CarPool(models.Model):

    # Relationship Fields
    car_inventory = models.ForeignKey(
        'cardealer.CarTypes',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="carpools", 
    )
    car_id = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="")
    car_location = GeopositionField()
    car_sale_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    YEAR_CHOICES = []


    for r in range(1980, (datetime.datetime.now().year+1)):
        YEAR_CHOICES.append((r,r))


    year_manufacture = models.IntegerField(('year_manufacture'), choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.car_id

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.car_inventory

class CustomerBuyer(models.Model):

    buyer_car_buy = models.ForeignKey(
        'cardealer.CarPool',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="customer_buyer",default='0'
    )
    buyer_private_name = models.CharField(max_length=80,default='')
    buyer_family_name = models.CharField(max_length=80,default='')
    buyer_private_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    transaction_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)




    def __str__(self):
        return self.buyer_private_name + ' '+ self.buyer_family_name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.buyer_private_name + ' '+ self.buyer_family_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, simply expand the 'save' method

```
class CustomerBuyer(models.Model):

    buyer_car_buy = models.ForeignKey(
        'cardealer.CarPool',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="customer_buyer",default='0'
    )
    buyer_private_name = models.CharField(max_length=80,default='')
    buyer_family_name = models.CharField(max_length=80,default='')
    buyer_private_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    transaction_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.buyer_private_name + ' '+ self.buyer_family_name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.buyer_private_name + ' '+ self.buyer_family_name

    def save(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        super(CustomerBuyer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.buyer_car_buy.car_sale_status = True
        self.buyer_car_buy.save()
```